# Could new TCP thread gets connection timeout due to another thread using the same destintation IP/port?

Tags: java, tcplistener

I have an Open GTS from Geotelematics running fine on UDP. Now we want to add TCP support, so I made some changes to enable it and it seems to work ok except that the TCP commands from the server to the device don't reach the device if the command is send asynchronously.

When the device sends something to the server the server search commands for this device in the DB and sends the ACK and the command, this works ok.

Now a TCP socket is waiting for a preconfigured period of 3 minutes; if I try to send a command the server creates a new thread and try to send the async command and gets a timeout after 5 seconds. Also the device doesn't receive anything.

Could it be that this timeout is caused by the the other thread that has a connection to the device on this IP/port connection?

I'm thinking that I should use the thread that already has a connection to the device and not create a new one, but, since there's a lot of devices running, there's a lot of threads too and I don't know how to send a "message" to that specific thread that has the connection to that specific device.

Any hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> Could it be that this timeout is caused by the the other thread that has a connection to the device on this IP/port connection?

TCP connections are unique, it is impossible to have two tcp socket connections with the same source port and IP while also having the same destination port and IP.

[TCPIPguide.com](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPIPSocketsandSocketPairsProcessandConnectionIden-2.htm)